# How to Remove Custom HTML Error Pages - .htaccess Not Found

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I have these custom HTML error pages I made a good while ago... error404.html, error403.html, etc.

The thing is, I thought I set up an htaccess file somewhere to specify on error 404 go to error404.html...  But I can't find that .htaccess file anywhere.

How are these things working?

If it matters I pay for shared hosting from 1and1.

Comment: Well, you can simply create these files if you really have. It is just files. Not diamonds. If you are stuck with a provider _not_ offering you any better means of configuration, then you simply take a text editor and create those files.

Comment: Something is pointing to those files.  I figured it was an .htaccess file. If I enter an incorrect path, it directs me to the the 404 file.  If I delete the 404 file, it goes to the 1and1 not found page...  You might suggest deleting them if I didn't want the files anymore, but if I delete error500.html and a 500 error happens, it will try to direct to that page and then show the 1and1 not found page, which isnt exactly accurate...

Comment: Sounds like you are looking at cached results...

Comment: It is not though.  error404.html is upload to the server, I get directed there with a bad url. error404.html is deleted from the server, I get sent to the 1and1 not found page. Upload error404.html to the server again and it is pointing back there.   I am literally puzzled.  I swear I could remember adding directives to a .htaccess file, but now it is no where to be found.

Comment: Well, if you really _did_ create such a file (you did not say so in the question, why not?), then finding it should be as easy as a `find . -name ".htaccess"`... Apart from that: remember that a file who's name starts with a dot is considered "hidden" in unixoid systems. So take care to list folders using the `-a` flag...

Comment: Soo maybe I didn't create an .htaccess file after all... Although that is one way of accomplishing the custom error pages.  I must have done it before and that is why it stuck in my head.  Thank you for the help!  Info here: https://www.genealogy-web-creations.com/create-custom-error-page.html

Comment: You can obviously do the same thing in the actual host configuration. And actually that is the preferred place to implement such rules for various reasons. Or, if this is a shared hosting provider then changes are that the rules exist globally and you only need to create the files. That certainly should be documented though, so _did_ you read the documentation the hosting service provider provides?

Comment: @arkascha condescending much?  Shared host (1and1) I did not see any documentation regarding this.  Closest I saw was this, which was not applicable.  https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/apache/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages/

Comment: I do apologize if I stepped on your toes. But please understand that all I said is that _if_ that is the case then it certainly _should_ be documented. Me asking if you read the documentation was an attempt to find out if there is such a setting. Since you did not mention such a thing, not the absence of the same I wondered if you read the documentation. Sorry if you read an accusation from that. Bye.